# Should I store file in database or just the location to that file?

Tags: database, file, file-upload

Which is the better practice to store file? Directly store the file in database or just the location to that file?

Comment: I'm surprised - this question is still in open discussion/debate? And it is not any duplicate, hmmm...

Comment: Looks similar to this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/should-binary-files-be-stored-in-the-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.  You need to consider several things.

1. If you have a mickey mouse freeware database, meaning that it does not handle blobs appropriately (reads the blobs on every `SELECT`; does not store the blobs in a separate physical structure to the row; very slow with blobs; etc)

   - keep the files outside, store only the location
   - manually deal with the syncing of row.location vs the file system
2. If you have an enterprise SQL Platform, it is no problem at all to keep the blobs inside the database.  In fact, retrieval is faster.  These do not read the blobs on every `SELECT`, they are stored in a separate physical structure to the rows. The one extra read to get the blob if the `SELECT` requests it, is not a "performance problem".
3. The `PAGESIZE` in genuine SQL databases can be set as 2k; 4k; 8k; or 16k.

   - 2k is perfect for OLTP (small rows, small Transactions: you do not want to move 8K on every IO operation)
   - larger sizes are relevant based on how much OLAP you cater for

     - in your case, the average size of the files
     - there will be some waste in the unused portion of the last page, *per* row/blob.
4. The **disadvantage** of keeping the blobs in the database is, your database backups will be significantly larger.

   - Some enterprise databases (eg. SAP/Sybase) recognise that a page has not changed, and excludes it from the incremental backups
   - others have no incremental database backups.
5. The **advantage** of keeping the blobs in the database is:

   - data and referential integrity.  You will not have the problem of having the rows that are out of synch with the blobs
   - the blobs are included in the backup: otherwise, upon a restore, the task of syncing the restored database with the restored files is a major problem.
   - *I completed an assignment last year, where the customer had 130GB of data in the db, and  700GB of documents stored outside the db.  After ten years of problems, they bit the bullet, and moved the documents into the db.

     Guess what, what was supposed to be a simple job (long but simple, because the references were supposed to be absolutely correct), ended up being massive, because there were so many (a) duplicates, and (b) invalid references.

     The resulting database was 630GB, there were 100GB of dupes. 2K pagesize.*

#### Responses to Comments

1. Slash or Backslash
   Easy.

   - In the database, store slash only.
   - You need a way of identifying the target system, and an `IsWindoze` indicator.  It should be higher up in the table hierarchy, not at the level where the `Filename` is located.
   - Whenever you report or display the `Filename` column, if `IsWindoze`, change the slashes to backslashes.

   You will have a similar problem with the DriveLetter and colon `D:`, which Unix does not have.  Allow it only if `IsWindoze`.

Comment: I have to store files on a system that may be on different kinds of OS, and one of the stupid things I encounter is the slash (/) or backslash (/) for the physical path of the file.

Comment: @Truong: Thanks. I added a response in my Answer.

Comment: Is SQLite a mickey mouse database?

Comment: @9716278  1) All the freeware "sql" & Oracle are mickey mouse: not SQL compliant, has extra features, but not the core requirement.  PostGres is the worst, it does not even have a true language, or ACID Transactions.  2) SQLite is mickey mouse lite.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid storing files in your database.  Most don't deal with them well.

Comment: Just to add, it is generally a bad idea - the only time it becomes even remotely viable is when you're dealing with a database where you can guarantee the record will be in memory when you need it, and thus served from there. But under almost every situation, the filesystem is a better place for it.

Comment: I find difficult to store file larger than 10mb in db while file system is great for this for years.

Comment: Still dunno what the BLOB and CLOB in MySQL are for?

Comment: @truong-ha, BLOBs and CLOBS are useful for smaller pieces of pertinent information, say checksums for your files.  There are better tools for serving files.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer: it depends on your engine.

- A page size of 2k hasn't been used since the 1990s for SQL Server. Oracle defaults to 8K, SQL Server is 8K. Only Sybase AFAIK is still in the last century.
- SQL Server now offers [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) which combines the best of both worlds, as Oracle has done for longer with BFILE
- SQL Server and Oracle offer on disk and backup compression

I'm sure PostgresSQL at least offers similar features.

Note: this is mainly to offer alternatives to PerformanceDBA's FUD

Comment: 1) It is stupid to transfer 8K on every single I/O operation, if the rows are small (Relational Normalised), but that is MS SQL Server.  Especially if it is a high-throughput OLTP system.  Further, the locking granularity for PageLocks would be larger and concurrency would suffer.  Oh wait, you have `RecordIds`; wide records; and row level locking, no concept of OLTP.  2) SAP/Sybase has 95% of the Wall St market (hint: high-end OLTP).  Wall St still use 2GB disks.  3) PostGres is anti-SQL.  4) *Alternatives* ? The Q is not about compression.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method is to store the file in the filesystem and store the location of the file in the database. The reasoning for this has to do with how databases physically allocate space on disk (usually in 8k or 16k chunks). Dropping large files in there causes your database to use different mechanisms to store the files (SQL Server calls this [row overflow data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981.aspx)). Typically these kind of pages are located out of the normal table, so every logical read for a  row results in two physical reads on disk. Needless to say, this isn't good for performance.